# Text formating is not applied in CLI - using PICOCLI java

Tags: command-line-interface, picocli

I've been trying to display formatted texts on **CLI**. I tried the exact same code provided in **picocli** **docs [(doc link)](https://picocli.info/#_ansi_colors_and_styles)**, but the formatting does not seem to be applied.

Please help me to identify my mistake.

**Expected output**

[image: Example of the formatting]

**My code**

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import picocli.CommandLine;
import picocli.CommandLine.Command;
import picocli.CommandLine.Help.Ansi;

@Command(name = "test", mixinStandardHelpOptions = true, version = "test 1.0",
   description = "Custom @|bold,underline styles|@ and @|fg(red) colors|@.")
public class Interpreter  implements Callable<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception { // your business logic goes here...
        String str = Ansi.AUTO.string("@|red Hello, colored world!|@");
        System.out.println(str);
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
            
        CommandLine prompt = new CommandLine(new Interpreter());
        int exitCode = prompt.execute(args);
        
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
```

**My output** (formatting is not getting applied)

[image: my output]

PS. Im using **picocli v 4.5.2**, exporting the project as **runnable** **jar**, and building it to **.exe** using **Launch4j**.
Executing the result **exe** in command prompt of windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get ANSI colors in Windows, you need to do some extra work. The best way is to add the [Jansi](http://fusesource.github.io/jansi/) library to your classpath.

To use Jansi, you need to enable it in your application:

```java
import org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiConsole;
// ...
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnsiConsole.systemInstall(); // enable colors on Windows
    new CommandLine(new Interpreter()).execute(args);
    AnsiConsole.systemUninstall(); // cleanup when done
}
```

If you are interested in creating a native Windows CLI executable with [GraalVM](https://picocli.info/#_graalvm_native_image) (instead of using Launch4j), then be aware that Jansi by itself is [insufficient](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi/issues/162) to show colors. This is partly because GraalVM requires configuration and partly because Jansi internally depends on non-standard system properties, without a graceful fallback if these properties are absent (as is the case in GraalVM).

You  may be interested in combining Jansi with [picocli-jansi-graalvm](https://github.com/remkop/picocli-jansi-graalvm) until this issue is fixed. Example usage:

```java
import picocli.jansi.graalvm.AnsiConsole; // not org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiConsole
// ...
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int exitCode;
    try (AnsiConsole ansi = AnsiConsole.windowsInstall()) {
        exitCode = new CommandLine(new Interpreter()).execute(args);
    }
    System.exit(exitCode);
}
```

See also the picocli user manual section on [ANSI colors in Windows](https://picocli.info/#_windows).